# how to differ start date and end date in a table views

Tags: datetime

in D7 i have a date field with start date and end date and configured like start=now and end date=+30days. both dates are displayed well in two columns in a table views seperately. now i want a third column to dispaly like end date-start date = 30days. how? any help please.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the third column should show?  Do you just want to show the phrase "30 days"?

Comment: no actualy it should display "time left".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global php field where you have the end date available as a token, you can get the current time using now and then get the difference between the 2 dates in days.

Comment: tried the same but not done. can u explain in more detail please?